# Which DirectShow source filters are used by WMP?

Tags: directshow, windows-media-player

I'm trying to split a `*.mov` file in to raw audio an raw video. I have a `DirectShow` filter which is working as decoder for the video stream and Windows Media Player can actually see and use it to play this video file but I having a hard time figuring out how does it work exactly since I need to compose a complex DirectShow graph. 
I assumed that WMP will use `WM ASF Rreader` but if I try to add this filter to the graph in GraphEdit with *.mov file as parameter it's failing with `0xc00d0026` error code which makes sense since it's suppose to work with uncompressed formats only. 

Which other DirectShow source filters can be used by WMP in order to split a *.mov video file in to raw video and audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Media Player (current versions, not ancient) does not use DirectShow for MOV files. Instead, it uses Media Foundation.

FYI: `0xC00D0026` is `NS_E_UNRECOGNIZED_STREAM_TYPE` "The specified protocol is not recognized. Be sure that the file name and syntax, such as slashes, are correct for the protocol."

I suppose you can find suitable DirectShow components to demultiplex MOV files: [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.su/mkv/), [GDCL MPEG-4 Demultiplexer](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/) are among widely used.

Comment: As far as I know when you're opening a file in WMP it attempts to play it with Media Foundation and if fails it will try to use DirectShow. I belive it is exactly what happening in my case since the only available way decode a video stream in my *.mov files for WMP is to use DirectShow fileter because of very specific codec which is present in the system only as QuickTime component and DirectShow filter. And I highly doubt WMP Media Foundation can use QT components.

Comment: Your belief is unlikely to be correct. But you can check it out: Windows SDK topoedit plays MOV files, so they are playable via MF, and WMP does not fail. In the same time you can use DirectShowSpy to make sure whether WMP builds any DS graphs or not - you will see it does not use DS. There is a small chance WMP plays through DS, using third party components - DirectShowSpy will reveal it and the details.

Comment: You were right. It was a 3rd party demultiplexer which was installed on the test PC without me knowing. And I already tried both Haali and GDCL demultiplexers. None of them are able to split DVCPro50  video stream from a *.mov file. It was incredibly easy to work with this format in MacOS but in Windows I can't find any reliable way to use it with DirectShow. I'm using Raylight Decoder to view those files in QuickTime, also there is Raylight Decoder DirectShow filter but input pin of it is MEDIATYPE_Video type but since I can't split a video stream I'm unable to use it.

Comment: GDCL demultiplexer is available in source code, so maybe it might appear that it's reasonably easy to extend its support to DVCPRO50. You still need a decoder of course.

Comment: Yep. I've been able to finally demultiplex that .mov file with "extended" version of GDCL. It's bit buggy yet but at least that's a start. Thanks for an advice.